# How to scale google map(resources) for retina display?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm making custom google map for the webview in iPhone4 but all streets and fonts are unreadably small.

I've tried to set `window.devicePixelRatio = 2;` but nothing happen. I also set google map api to version "3" but no luck.

I know there is "sacle" parameter for "static map" but not for "map".

Does anyone how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "viewport" meta is the key for this problem.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

It works as charm for now :)